# cant remove list dot in draft js on backspace react-draft-wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I use draftJS to edit text in my project, and at the moment I'm faced with such a problem that if you include a list with dots or numbers in an empty editor, then it cannot be deleted with the backspace key
[my editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnEMK.png)

````
```<Editor
    editorState={description}
    toolbarStyle={editorStyles.toolbarStyle}
    editorStyle={editorStyles.editorStyle}
    onEditorStateChange={onChangeDescription}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    toolbar={toolbar}
  />```
````

Answer (score 0):

I just study draft.js. you can handle the key command by `RichUtils.handleKeyCommand`.
The code below is that i create a function `handleKeyCommandEn`.then it can handle backspace to remove list

```
import { EditorState, convertToRaw, ContentState,RichUtils } from "draft-js";

...
 const [editorStateEn, setEditorStateEn] = useState<EditorState>(EditorState.createEmpty());
    const handleKeyCommandEn = (command) => {
      const newState = RichUtils.handleKeyCommand(editorStateEn, command);
      if (newState) {
        setEditorStateEn(newState);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    };

...

                <Editor
                    editorState={editorStateEn}
                    wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
                    editorClassName="demo-editor"
                    onEditorStateChange={setEditorStateEn}
                    toolbar={{
                      options:['inline','blockType', 'fontSize', 'fontFamily', 'list', 'textAlign', 'remove', 'history'],
                      textAlign: { inDropdown: true },
                      inline :{options:['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough','superscript','subscript']}
                    }}
                    localization={{
                      locale: 'en',
                    }}
                    stripPastedStyles={true} // disable paste style
                    handleKeyCommand={handleKeyCommandEn}
                    placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: "editorPlaceholder" })}
                  />
```